# TypeScript infer dynamic type from first array element in second array element

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function `myFunc` which takes one argument. This argument is an object, where each property of the object is an array containing two elements:

```
myFunc({
  prop1: [value1, (value1) => { /*...*/ }],
  prop2: [value2, (value2) => { /*...*/ }],
});
```

As you can see, the first element can be anything (some user-specified value), and the second element is a function.

The function defined for the second element takes the first element as an argument.

For example:

```
// both functions returns true 

myFunc({
  prop1: ["hello", (str) => str === "hello"],
  prop2: [5, (num) => num === 5],
});
```

This is working as expected, but I cannot figure out how to infer the type of the first element, so that I can properly type the parameter of the function defined for the second element.

Essentially what I want is something like this:

```
// How do I infer the type of U from the first array element?

const myFunc = <T extends { [key: string]: [U, (u: U) => any] }>(t: T) => {
  // ...
}
```

The `myFunc` function takes a string-keyed object, with values that are arrays of two elements, where **the type of the first element is the same type as the parameter of the function defined for the second element**.

Is there some way I can infer the type of `U` from the first element, so that I can apply this type to the second element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript compiler is not perfect, it can't infer everything (yet), there are some details you (as developer) have to tell him. When you pass a function as an argument, you have to declare types of parameters that this function accepts. Otherwise TS compiler can not protect you (in other words: checking type of 'num' & 'str' arguments would be only possible in runtime) The best I was able to do to type your example is:

```
type TStingFunk = (y: string) => boolean
type TNumFunk = (y: number) => boolean
type PropTuple = [x: number, funk: TNumFunk ] | [x: string, funk: TStingFunk ]
interface IProp {
    prop1: PropTuple,
    prop2: PropTuple,
}
type TFunc = (prop: IProp) => void;

const myFunc:TFunc = ({
  prop1,
  prop2,
}) => {}

myFunc({
  prop1: ["hello", (str: string) => str === "hello"],
  prop2: [5, (num: number) => num === 5],
})
```

this compiles without errors and TS protects you from case when you pass wrong params to myFunc